# how to match a number values from two files by perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, numbers, match

I have a two text file separate by tab.
file 1:

```
 21             114352848          
  6             73853300       
 17             53191768      
 13             28008170          
 35             34642708  
 25             18912643
```

file2:

```
ABHD17B  1     85806534    85893402    
ACAT2    1     49011742    49029143    
ACTN4    21    114352846   114428174    
ADGRG6   1     33969266    34107014        
AFDN     17    55435472    55536326       
AGTPBP1  6     73853296    74033587       
AHI1     13    28008167    28198117       
AIG1     35    34642706    34886059       
AKAP12   25    41614908    41711677        
AKAP7    25    69361015    69483139        
AKT2     16    113380376   113406769         
ALDH16A1  1    107032288   107047268
```

output:

```
ACTN4    21    114352846   114428174  
AGTPBP1  6     73853296    74033587  
AHI1     13    28008167    28198117    
AIG1     35    34642706    34886059
```

I want to do the regex match by column.
first, I want to check the column 1 from file 1 match with column 2 from file 2. If yes, then check the column 2 from file 1 whether location at number range between column 3 and column 4 in file 2.

my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash;
my @values;
my @value;
my $line;
my $min;
my $max;
open my $IN1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN1>) {
my @values = split;
my $line = $values[1];
undef $hash{$values[0]};
}
close $IN1;
open my $IN2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN2>) {
chomp;
my @value = split;
my $min = $value[2];
my $max = $value[3];
if (exists $hash{$value[1]}) {
if ($line >= $min && $line <= $max){
  print "$_\n";
   }
 }
}
close $IN2;
```

I am not sure why my code doesn't work. 
I got the waring:
Use of uninitialized value $line in numeric ge (>=) at .pl line XX

Then, I would like to know are there other effective way to write scripts for this example.

Comment: `undef $hash{$values[0]};` What are you trying to do with that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `$line` is not used in the second loop at all. In the first loop, you declare another `$line` shadowing the outer variable. It's better not to declare variables in wider scope than actually needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
open my $IN1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN1>) {
    my @values = split;
    $hash{ $values[0] } = $values[1];
}

open my $IN2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN2>) {
    my @values = split;
    my ($min, $max) = @values[2, 3];
    print if exists $hash{ $values[1] }
          && $hash{ $values[1] } > $min
          && $hash{ $values[1] } < $max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assign or use `$line` in your second loop except for that single comparison. What is its purpose. Did you maybe want to use `$hash{ $value[1] }` instead?

Comment: I use $line at $line >= $min && $line <= $max. to check the number is in the number range or not

Comment: I used to  try $hash{ $value[1] }, but still can not work. I got the error message about the hash

Comment: What error message? Maybe you have whitespace at the end of your input lines? `s/\s+$//;` after (or instead of the) `chomp` can help there.